# Extracting a number in string inside brackets with Regexextract

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am trying to extract number only (float?) from accounting numbers in google sheet with abbrev. units like K,M,B and sometimes in a bracket when negative. Sorry I am so new in regex, how to write a regular express covering different possibilities like (213M),(31.23B)?

```
\(([0-9.]+\.\[0-9.]+)\)
```

Comment: If you do not need the letters, but want to match them, `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[KMB]`. If you must check for the parentheses - `\((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[KMB]\)`

Comment: If the numbers can sometimes be between brackets when negative, you could use 2 capturing groups with an alternation `\((?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\])[KMB]\)` https://regex101.com/r/VED0MS/1. You could also make them optional, but then it will also match then one of the brackets is present `\(\[?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\]?[KMB]\)` https://regex101.com/r/gOpuOq/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[KMB]\)
```

**Details**

- `\(` - a literal `(` char
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1:

  - `-?` - an optional `-`
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of a dot followed with 1+ digits
- `[KMB]` - a character class matching `K`, `M` or `B`
- `\)`  - a literal `)` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vqWVPg/1).